# CORS requset did not send cookie

Tags: javascript, web, cookies, axios, cross-domain

I set a cookie under the `www.example.com`, and then when I send CORS requests (POST) to `api-request.com`, the cookie is not carried in the request header.

In this case, whether the cookie can be sent. Or I have to set the cookie to `api-request.com`.

ps: The `SameSite` of the cookie is `None` and I set `withCredentials: true` with Axios.

Answer (score 0):

For browser, its not allowed to send cookies if different domain, even you can't make XHR request, but if `api-request.com` has headers

- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true`

you can send the cookies

For node.js you can send custom cookies or any headers.

Comment: I can successfully send the cookie under the `api-request.com` in the CORS request.But the cookie under the `www.example.com` isn't send.

Comment: make sure `example.com` allowed cors and custom headers (cookies)